# Calculate in a table with different cells - SQL Server / T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have in my database (SQL Server 2008 R2) a table like this:

```
 ID......Team...........Name......Age
 102     Barcelona      Mike      15
 103     Barcelona      Peter     10
 104     Barcelona      Jacke     10
 105     Barcelona      Jonas     10
 106     Real Madrid    Michael   20
 107     Real Madrid    Terry     26
 108     Chelsea        James     26
 109     Chelsea        Arthur    23
 110     Chelsea        Spence    22
```

1. How can I loop the field 'Team' and know that, there are records like Barcelona, Real Madrid and Chelsea.
2. After that I want to calculate the sum of the team player of each team.

For Barcelona: -> 10 + 10 + 10 + 15 = 45

For Real Madrid: -> 20 + 26 = 46

For Chelsea: -> 26 + 23 + 22 = 71

1. Fill each result in a separate variable.

The whole calculation should be done in a stored procedure.

The second thing, if I have a table like this:

```
 ID......Team...........Name......HeaderGoal......FreeKickGoal
 104     Barcelona      Mike      2               1
 105     Barcelona      Peter     1               0
 106     Real Madrid    Michael   0               1
 107     Real Madrid    Terry     0               1
 108     Chelsea        James     0               0
 109     Chelsea        Arthur    2               3
 110     Chelsea        Spence    4               0
```

1. How can I loop the field 'Team' and know that, there are records like Barcelona, Real Madrid and Chelsea.
2. After that I want to calculate the sum of all Goals of each team with the goal type HeaderGoal and FreeKickGoal.

Example for

-> Barcelona: 2+1+1 = 4

-> Real Madrid: 1+1 = 2

-> Chelsea: 2 + 3 + 4 = 9

1. Fill each result in a separate variable.

The whole calculation should be done in a stored procedure.

I hope you can help me!
BK_

Comment: how do you differentiate between headerGoals and Freekicks ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly it looks like what you want are aggregates for each group, something that is easily accomplished with the [GROUP BY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) clause.

For the first query you would use:

```
SELECT team, SUM(age) AS 'Sum of the team' 
FROM table 
GROUP BY team
```

This will give this result:

```
Team                 Sum of the team
-------------------- ---------------
Barcelona            45
Chelsea              71
Real Madrid          46
```

and for the second:

```
SELECT team, SUM(headergoal + freekickgoal) AS 'Sum of goals' 
FROM table 
GROUP BY team
```

which will give this result:

```
Team                 Sum of goals
-------------------- ------------
Barcelona            4
Chelsea              9
Real Madrid          2
```

In your example data you list the desired result for the first part for Chelsea as 45 but I guess that is just a typo as you omitted one of Chelseas rows in the calculation?

As for turning it into a stored procedure I can just tell you that it's easy and refer you to the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx) as I won't do all the work for you...

Edit: added `merge into`as a response to a comment:

To insert the result of the second query into an existing table you can use either a simple `INSERT` statement like this:

```
INSERT table_with_team_and_goals 
SELECT team, SUM(headergoal + freekickgoal)
FROM table 
GROUP BY team
```

or `MERGE INTO` which might be better if you intend to run the query many times (the target table will then be updated if the team already exist in it):

```
MERGE INTO table_with_team_and_goals AS target
USING (SELECT Team, SUM(headergoal + freekickgoal) AS goals FROM table_with_goals GROUP BY team) AS source
ON target.team=source.team
 WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET goals = source.goals
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
        INSERT (Team, Goals)
        VALUES (source.team, source.goals);
```

Comment: Thank you a million for your answer. Yes, your right, thats a typo.
No that is enough, you dont have to do all the work for me :-) Thank you for the reference.

Comment: @Bk_ Happy to help. If the answer was helpful to you please consider accepting it and/or upvoting :)

Comment: One question... is there a possibility to write the result in a table? Same like the result of the SELECT statement.

Comment: @Bk_ Not sure I get what you want, but if it is to get the results from both the previous queries into a new table it's certainly possible.

Comment: Mhh.. my question is more for the second part of the main question. The SELECT result of headergoal and freekickgoal should be written in a table(which is allready exist) with the fields 'team' and 'goals'. Which command should I know for realize that?

Comment: @Bk_ I updated my answer with a solution to your last question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TEAM , Name, COUNT(TEAM) As GoalsPerTeam, COUNT(NAME) As GoalPerPlayer
FROM TABLE 
GROUP BY TEAM , Name
```

This query will give you tolal goals scored by per player and per team .

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Sum age by team
SELECT Team, SUM(Age) SumAge
FROM
(
    SELECT Id, Team, Name, Age FROM
    (
        VALUES
        (102, 'Barcelona'  , 'Mike'   , 15),
        (103, 'Barcelona'  , 'Peter'  , 10),
        (104, 'Barcelona'  , 'Jacke'  , 10),
        (105, 'Barcelona'  , 'Jonas'  , 10),
        (106, 'Real Madrid', 'Michael', 20),
        (107, 'Real Madrid', 'Terry'  , 26),
        (108, 'Chelsea'    , 'James'  , 26),
        (109, 'Chelsea'    , 'Arthur' , 23),
        (110, 'Chelsea'    , 'Spence' , 22)
    ) AS X(Id, Team, Name, Age)
) X
GROUP BY Team

-- Sum goals by team
SELECT Team, SUM(HeaderGoal + FreeKickGoal) Goals
FROM
(
    SELECT Id, Team, Name, HeaderGoal, FreeKickGoal FROM
    (
        VALUES
        (104, 'Barcelona'  , 'Mike'   , 2, 1),
        (105, 'Barcelona'  , 'Peter'  , 1, 0),
        (106, 'Real Madrid', 'Michael', 0, 1),
        (107, 'Real Madrid', 'Terry'  , 0, 1),
        (108, 'Chelsea'    , 'James'  , 0, 0),
        (109, 'Chelsea'    , 'Arthur' , 2, 3),
        (110, 'Chelsea'    , 'Spence' , 4, 0)
    ) AS X(Id, Team, Name, HeaderGoal, FreeKickGoal)
) X
GROUP BY Team
```