# Change from SQL to SQL-CE - Syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I've already asked a question for the following code:  [Here is the question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483517/calculate-in-a-table-with-different-cells-sql-server-t-sql)

I have the following sql syntax that I used in my database query (SQL Server).

```
MERGE INTO table_with_team_and_goals AS target
USING (SELECT Team, SUM(headergoal + freekickgoal) AS goals FROM table_with_goals GROUP BY team) AS source
ON target.team=source.team
 WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET goals = source.goals
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
        INSERT (Team, Goals)
        VALUES (source.team, source.goals);
```

I'm changing now to sql-server-ce (compact edition).
I could find out that, some commands which are supported by sql aren't supported by SQL Server Compact. (like marge into)

How can I change the code, that it works on SQL Server Compact.

Thank you for the help!
BK

**Edit:**

The Table: **table_player_goal_ratings** -> contains following data:

```
 ID......Team...........Name......HeaderGoal......FreeKickGoal
 104     Barcelona      Mike      2               1
 105     Barcelona      Peter     0               0
 106     Real Madrid    Michael   0               2
 107     Real Madrid    Terry     0               2
 108     Chelsea        James     0               0
 109     Chelsea        Arthur    1               2
 110     Chelsea        Spence    1               2
```

Now i want to insert in following table(**table_team_goal_ratings**) these data like this:

```
 FC.............Goals
 Barcelona      3
 Real Madrid    4
 Chelsea        6
```

Comment: (Well, [you probably don't to use `MERGE` anyway, even in SQL Server](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/). Also, you should consider SQL Express / LocalDB instead of CE.)

Comment: So the table `table_team_goal_ratings` is currently empty, and you want to know how to populate it with these totals?

Comment: @AaronBertrand : Thank you for your comment. Yes, the table "table_team_goal_ratings" is empty and I want to know how to populate it with these totals.

Comment: The problem is, I want to write a program, which has a local DB. That is why, I choose CE.

Comment: I'll try not to point out that LocalDB is, well, a local DB. And that CE is pretty much dead (no further development) and it has a significant set of limitations compared to Express and LocalDB. You should look it up so you know what you're dismissing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand You are completely right, but I can't demand from my customers, that they should first install SQL Express on their computer to use my computer. my programm to small for the effort. Do you know, that is possible only to install the SQL Services on Clients? Because that would solve my problem. I would use normal Service-based DB, which supports normal SQL and not CE.

Comment: Hint: SqlLocalDB.msi is a standalone installer, does not require a full Express service, and can be included as part of your app; with all the upsides, the only downside is that it takes more disk space (~140MB). Please read for yourself, [start here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2012/02/26/sql-express-v-localdb-v-sql-compact-edition.aspx).

Comment: Also see [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2694/getting-started-with-sql-server-2012-express-localdb/) and [here](http://www.i-programmer.info/news/84-database/4086-up-and-runninng-with-localdb.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `UPDATE` and `INSERT`:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

UPDATE A
SET goals = B.goals
FROM dbo.table_with_team_and_goals A
INNER JOIN (SELECT team, SUM(headergoal + freekickgoal) AS goals 
            FROM table_with_goals 
            GROUP BY team) B
    ON A.team = B.team

INSERT INTO dbo.table_with_team_and_goals(team, goals) 
SELECT team, goals
FROM (  SELECT team, SUM(headergoal + freekickgoal) AS goals 
        FROM table_with_goals 
        GROUP BY team) A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM dbo.table_with_team_and_goals
                 WHERE team = A.team)

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could I ask you to explain what the code do? Thank you!

Comment: From where do you have A and B?

Comment: `A` and `B` are the tables aliases that I chose to use, could've been anything really. It was just for simplicity

Comment: Thank you for your comment Lamak. But maybe I dont ask my question clearly. I want to try following -> see my question, i've edited it. Thanks..

Comment: @Bk_ it seems like what this query is doing except that you changed the table names

Comment: Even if i try this on a database with these table names, following error message shows: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 3 Token line offset = 1, Token in error = FROM]